# Memory Corruption Ruby on Rails with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, database-migration, amazon-aurora

when I deploy my Ruby on Rails app on Elastic Beanstalk I get this error:
Application update failed at 2020-06-20T23:27:17Z with exit status 134 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/12_db_migration.sh failed.

In my logs I have:
Error in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake db:migrate': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00005643b34ce420

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.2 and Aurora MySQL (version 5.7.12) on Elastic Beanstalk

Thank you.